# How to add data inside an array with another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this data

```
string(94) "[{"value":"Charger"},{"value":"Bag Only"},{"value":"Data Privacy Filter"},{"value":"Headset"}]"
```

now I have set an array like this

```
$accessoriesID = array ("Charger" => "11043" , 
"Mouse" => "11044", 
"Bag With Strap" => "11045", 
"Bag Only" => "11046",
"Cable Lock" => "11047",
"Data Privacy Filter" => "11048",
"Numeric Lock" => "11049",
"Headset" => "11050",
"HDMI to VGA adapter" => "11051",
"LAN Adapter" => "12223",
"Others (Please include in the remarks box below.)" => "11052"
);
```

now here's my code

```
foreach($_POST['Acc'] as $accessories)
{
   $arrAccesories[]['value'] = $accessories;    
}

var_dump(json_encode($arrAccesories));
```

what I am trying to achieve is to merge the 2 arrays with the same value so the expected output should be like this

```
string(94) "[{"value":"Charger", "id": "11043"},{"value":"Bag Only", "id": "11046"},{"value":"Data Privacy Filter", "id": "11048"},{"value":"Headset", "id": "11050"}]"
```

I just want some guidance on how to achieve this or reference so I can learn to do these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use normal for loop:

```
$arrAccesories = '[{"value":"Charger"},{"value":"Bag Only"},{"value":"Data Privacy Filter"},{"value":"Headset"}]';
$arrAccesories = json_decode($arrAccesories, true);

$accessoriesID = array ("Charger" => "11043", 
"Mouse" => "11044", 
"Bag With Strap" => "11045", 
"Bag Only" => "11046",
"Cable Lock" => "11047",
"Data Privacy Filter" => "11048",
"Numeric Lock" => "11049",
"Headset" => "11050",
"HDMI to VGA adapter" => "11051",
"LAN Adapter" => "12223",
"Others (Please include in the remarks box below.)" => "11052"
);

for ($i=0; $i < count($arrAccesories); $i++) {
  $value = $arrAccesories[$i]['value'];
  if (isset($accessoriesID[$value])) {
    $arrAccesories[$i]['id'] = $accessoriesID[$value];
  }
}

var_dump(json_encode($arrAccesories));
```

Comment: just an empty `string(2) "[]"`

Comment: try to dump `$arrAccesories` only before json_encode functionality

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_map()` if you prefer functional style code, but a `foreach()` is perfectly suitable.  If you decode the json into an array of objects, you don't even need to explicitly modify by reference with `&`.

In case a value is not found as a key in your lookup array, it is a good idea to use a fallback/default value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QJObG))

```
$arrAccesories = '[{"value":"Charger"},{"value":"Bag Only"},{"value":"Data Privacy Filter"},{"value":"Headset"}]';
$arrAccesories = json_decode($arrAccesories);

$accessoriesID = [
    "Charger" => "11043", 
    "Mouse" => "11044", 
    "Bag With Strap" => "11045", 
    "Bag Only" => "11046",
    "Cable Lock" => "11047",
    "Data Privacy Filter" => "11048",
    "Numeric Lock" => "11049",
    "Headset" => "11050",
    "HDMI to VGA adapter" => "11051",
    "LAN Adapter" => "12223",
    "Others (Please include in the remarks box below.)" => "11052"
];
$default = $accessoriesID['Others (Please include in the remarks box below.)'];

foreach ($arrAccesories as $row) {
    $row->id = $accessoriesId[$row->value] ?? $default;
}

echo json_encode($arrAccesories);
```

Output:

```
[{"value":"Charger","id":"11052"},{"value":"Bag Only","id":"11052"},{"value":"Data Privacy Filter","id":"11052"},{"value":"Headset","id":"11052"}]
```